# How does go know where to get packages from

Tags: go, go-modules

When I import a package in a go application (using modules and vscode with golang plugin):

```
import (
   cors "goa.design/plugins/cors/dsl"
)
```

go automatically retrieves the package. 
How does go know where to get it from? 
I figured it simply pulls the sources from github.com, but the repository for this project is at `https://github.com/goadesign/goa` no `.` in the name. 
And if I change the import to:

```
import (
   cors "goa.design/plugins/v3/cors/dsl"
)
```

It retrieves the `v3` package. I would gladly RTFM, but not sure which FM I need to read.

Btw: this is my second day on `go` so this is magic to me.

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Comment: And for the details on module versions: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_compatibility_and_semantic_versioning

Comment: Note to self: go vanity urls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple, check it out:

```
$> curl https://goa.design/plugins/cors/dsl
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


  <meta name="go-import" content="goa.design/plugins git https://github.com/goadesign/plugins">
  <meta name="go-source" content="goa.design/plugins _ https://github.com/goadesign/plugins/tree/master/{/dir} https://github.com/goadesign/plugins/blob/master{/dir}/{file}#L{line}">
```

The key here is in the  tag named "go-import". When `go get` requests https://goa.design/..., it hits that HTML file and knows that "goa.design/...." must be retrieved using git from https://github.com/goadesign/plugins.

Here is a good [article](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/2015/08/26/Hosting_Go_code_on_Github_with_custom_import_path)